# How to import images to my application in C#?

Tags: c#, image

I am new in C# programming, I just wanted to know how can I import some bitmap images to my form application for future processing and then show it to my image box?

Comment: be specific? what you mean by import image? to where?

Comment: How far in the future?

Comment: i mean loading an image to my application and call it for example bmp1 and then display that image to my image box1. i know it sound very silly but the rest of my programme depend on this very basic stage;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add the bitmap image as an embedded resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and access it from code for processing.

Comment: could you please give an example? i have some problem with    "string inputFile3 = @"C:\CaptchaExamples\CAPTCHA-03.bmp";"